# Starting a python server hijacks the lxterminal

Tags: python, server, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get my Rasberry Pi 3B running Python commands in one terminal while running a local server for camera streaming all from a single boot file.

Everything works on its own, but as soon as I use a Python command to start the server, the terminal is hijacked by the server. Any ideas how to prevent this from Python alone?

```
import io
import os
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
camera = PiCamera()

    class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
        allow_reuse_address = True
        daemon_threads = True
        logging = False
    output = StreamingOutput()
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

I tried this, but it does not stop the server overtaking the terminal.

```
class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        if self.server.logging:
            server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.log_message(self, format, *args)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, no thanks to you lurkers.

Solution:

I made a bash script to start the server from a virtual environment

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh
# navigate to home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home
sleep 5
cd /
cd home/pi
. ../env/bin/activate; python bootServer.py
cd /
```

And added it to crontab

```
sudo crontab -e
```

With the line

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/filename.sh >/home/pi/logfolder/cronlog 2>&1
```

It now boots on startup and no longer hijaks my terminal.
Hope this helps someone someday.